# What is the best approach in python: multiple OR or IN in if statement?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, design-patterns

What is the best approach in python: *multiple OR* or *IN* in if statement? Considering performance and best pratices.

```py
if cond == '1' or cond == '2' or cond == '3' or cond == '4': pass
```

OR

```py
if cond in ['1','2','3','4']: pass
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best approach is to use a *set*:

```
if cond in {'1','2','3','4'}:
```

as membership testing in a set is O(1) (constant cost).

The other two approaches are equal in complexity; merely a difference in constant costs. Both the `in` test on a list and the `or` chain short-circuit; terminate as soon as a match is found. One uses a sequence of byte-code jumps (jump to the end if `True`), the other uses a C-loop and an early exit if the value matches. In the worst-case scenario, where `cond` does *not* match an element in the sequence either approach has to check *all* elements before it can return `False`. Of the two, I'd pick the `in` test any day because it is far more readable.

Comment: @JonathanSimonPrates: Use `frozenset(['1', '2', '3', '4'])` for older versions.

Comment: Python 2.7 does not have set constants, thus the `in tuple` is the best one for a small set of values.

Answer (score 4):

This actually depends on the version of Python. In **Python 2.7** there were no set constants in the bytecode, thus in Python 2 in the case of a fixed constant small set of values use a tuple:

```
if x in ('2', '3', '5', '7'):
    ...
```

A tuple is a constant:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: item in ('1','2','3','4'))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (('1', '2', '3', '4'))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python is also smart enough to optimize a constant list on Python 2.7 to a tuple:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: item in ['1','2','3','4'])
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (('1', '2', '3', '4'))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

But Python 2.7 bytecode (and compiler) lacks support for constant sets:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: item in {'1','2','3','4'})
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('2')
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 ('3')
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 ('4')
             15 BUILD_SET                4
             18 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Which means that the set in `if` condition needs to be rebuilt for each **test**.

---

However in **Python 3.4** the bytecode supports set constants; there the code evaluates to:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: item in {'1','2','3','4'})
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (frozenset({'4', '2', '1', '3'}))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

As for the multi-`or` code, it produces totally hideous bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: item == '1' or item == '2' or item == '3' or item == '4')
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     45
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 ('2')
             18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             21 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     45
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
             27 LOAD_CONST               3 ('3')
             30 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             33 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     45
             36 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (item)
             39 LOAD_CONST               4 ('4')
             42 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   45 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: With Python3.9.9, the frozenset comparison is the quickest. 

```>>> timeit.timeit("x in (1,2,3,4)", setup="x=3")
0.11902332499994372
>>> timeit.timeit("x in {1,2,3,4}", setup="x=3")
0.07512418700025592
```

Answer (score 3):

Pieters answer is the best in most cases.  However, in your specific case, I wouldn't use `in` or `or` but instead do this:

```
if 0 < int(cond) < 5:
```

If cond is '1', '2', '3', or '4', the if block will run.  Nice thing about this is that it is shorter than the other answers.

Comment: if _cond_ is guaranteed to be one char long, _int_ may be dropped _'0' < cond < '5'_ will work too