# Asking multiple things in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

im new to StackOverflow and Python, I am working on my first program that is not hello world, it is a simple rock, paper, scissors game.

So, my question is can you ask multiple things in an if statement?
quick sample

```
sport = raw_input("Whats a good sport?")
if sport == 'Football','Soccer','Hockey':
   print 'Those are fun sports!'
elif sport != 'Football','Soccer','Hockey':
print 'I dont like those sports!'
```

I know there are ways to fix that code but I am curious as to if that is a thing?

Comment: Lemme find the duplicate(s) .. :}

Comment: what about the logical operator or **||**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615020/what-is-the-best-approach-in-python-multiple-or-or-in-in-if-statement , http://stackoverflow.com/q/26891304/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `and` and `or`:

```
if sport == "Fooball" or sport == "Soccer":
    print "those are fun sports!"
```

You can also check for a string in a list (or in the following example, a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)) of strings:

```
if sport in ("Football", "Soccer", "Hockey"):
    print "those are fun sports"
```

Comment: Thank you for the hasty response! Sorry for my noobiness in python

Comment: Isn't that technically a tuple and not a list of strings?

Comment: @nalyd88: technically, yes it is a tuple. Conceptually it is a list of items. Considering that the person who asked the question knows absolutely nothing about programming, I didn't want to get into the differences.  I'll update my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regular expressions to find if the sport is fun or not. The benefit to regular expressions is that it makes it easy to handle different scenarios. For example if the user inputted `football` instead of `Football` you could still determine that the sport is fun or not.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[fF]ootball|[sS]occer|[hH]ockey')
sport = 'Football'
if pattern.search("Football"):
    print sport + " is fun"
else:
    print sport + " is not fun"
```

For more info:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/regex.htmlYou