# Break a while loop when two specific letters can be found in string

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a string variable (`mystring`). In a while loop the user can input the content of the string and I want to break the loop when it contains the letter `'a'` and the letter `'b'`. I tried the following:

```
mystring = ''

while 'a' or 'b' not in mystring:
    mystring = input('write:')
```

the while loop works perfect if I use just one of the letters (no `or` statement).
If I check mystring e.g. after inputting `'abacjihgea'` using

```
'a' and 'b' in mystring
```

it returns `True`. Shouldn't it break the while loop then?

Unfortunately I can't seem to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best approach in python: multiple OR or IN in if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615020/what-is-the-best-approach-in-python-multiple-or-or-in-in-if-statement) and [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: `while (a not in mystring) and (b not in mystring):`?

Comment: Thanks Thomas Weller! That did the trick!

Comment: @rdas I do not see that the dup target (question and answers) should help in this case, so I vote to reopen.

Comment: @Guy I mean, for people who are familiar with `in` and boolean expressions, the dup relation is easy to see but it is not for beginners not aware what they actually do. Look for example at `0 < x < 10` in Python which looks like school math but isn't...

Comment: @rdas BTW: is it possible to change the dup target to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/2932052 which contains answers explaining the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should check separately and with an and condition

```
while ('a' not in mystring) and ('b' not in mystring) :
     mystring=input()
```

A cleaner method is using set and intersection for multiple chars

```
while not {'a','b'}.issubset(mystring):
    mystring=input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression as well.
If order of letters is certain e.g. **a** followed by **b** then `a.*b` otherwise `(a.*b|b.*a)`.

```
import re
mystring = ''

while not re.search('(a.*b|b.*a)',mystring):
    mystring = input('write:')
```

Comment: not quite efficient and not good to generalize. What if you have a list of letters *variables* to search for: build a complex regex?